# Torque of Air Resistance on Ellipsoid

Tags: torque, drag, rigid-body-dynamics

Imagine an non-rotating arbitrary free, rigid ellipsoid with in some arbitrary direction with velocity $\vec v$. Assume linear drag ($\vec F=KA\vec v$ for some constant K, where A is the cross section area). What is the total torque of air resistance on the ellipsoid?
One question I think might be important is that is the symmetry of arbitrary ellipsoids sufficient to guarantee zero torque, no matter which direction the ellipsoid's velocity is. I decided it might not be and decided to post the question here after my calculations got quite a bit too involved.

Comment: Why assume linear drag?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.dept.aoe.vt.edu/~lutze/AOE3104/airfoilwings.pdf) should get you going in general.

Comment: @ja72 Well, I assumed linear drag as the velocities considered should be low. And I decided it would probably simplify the calculations. Also, I went through the paper, but I'm not quite sure what I can do with the contents of the paper.

Comment: It depends on what you consider the center of rotation of the ellipsoid. Are you assuming its center of area is where it is pivoted? That paper doesn't say anything about shapes like ellipsoids - only wings with sharp trailing edges. I would start with [*Potential flow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey The center of rotation of the ellipsoid is naturally its center of mass. I don't quite get your part on center of area. Also, how would potential flow help? Many thanks.